# bash removing slashes in front of directory names

Tags: bash, directory, ls

I'm trying to recapture some of the simplicity of the c-shell and tcsh. I had a simple alias that allowed me to list directories (`alias lsdd 'ls | grep /'`). I found a post with several solutions, none of which were particularly satisfying. For instance,

```
ls -d */
```

works well unless there are no sub-directories, in which case you get an error message--not exactly elegant.

```
echo */
```

doesn't give that error, but the list is not as easily readable as a single column.

So, I have been routing around in `/etc` to find where bash defines its `ls` command so that it uses color, and so that it strips the `/` following the directory name. That seems to be a great place to do some bud nipping. In what startup file does bash strip slashes from directory names in an `ls` command?

Comment: If you pass to `ls` a directory name which ends in a slash, `ls` also append a slash in the output. You can observe this when you do a `ls -d $HOME  /tmp/`: Your home directory will be listed without slash, while /tmp will be listed with slash.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list only directories without the trailing slash and in a single column `ls` is not necessarily the best utility. And aliases are somehow obsolete; functions are recommended nowadays.

```bash
lsdd() {
  local -a list=( */ )
  printf '%s\n' "${list[@]%/}"
}
```

If there are no sub-directories by default a single `*` is printed. To get rid of it we can temporarily set the `nullglob` option. In the following we record the option's initial state and restore it afterwards:

```bash
lsdd() {
  local tmp=$(shopt -p nullglob)
  shopt -s nullglob
  local -a list=( */ )
  printf '%s\n' "${list[@]%/}"
  eval "$tmp"
}
```